# Help needed regarding function

Tags: functions

For a fixed constant $k$ and for a particular value of $n$, but for all $x$, we have

$$ f(x)+f(x+1)+....+f (x+n)=k. $$
How do we find  the  period of  the function?

Comment: You may want to introduce some constraints, otherwise the constant function $f(x)=\frac{k}{n+1}\,$ has *any* real number as a period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^n f(x+i) = k$

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^n f(x+1+i) = \sum_\limits{i=0}^n f(x+i) + f(x+n+1) - f(x) = k$

$f(x+n+1) = f(x)$